# MySQL probelm in port: 3306

Tags: mysql

All websites on my VPS getting very slow, after dedcting the problem found that there are a line take 99.9% of the CPU:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql \
--plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin \
--user=mysql \
--log-error=/var/lib/mysql/cd.49.be.static.xlhost.com.err \
--pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/cd.49.be.static.xlhost.com.pid
```

Opened this file found nothing, everything goes right in this file.

**EDIT**:

etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

tried to know more, and closed all the content of my domains, also removed each database, one by one and nothing change still the same problem !

Could you help to know from where this error

Comment: That just means MySQL is taking up 99% of the cpu and that file is mysql's log file. You need to look at MySQL troubleshooting there's lot out there. Slow queries is usually a good place to start you can see what queries are causing high load on the CPU.

Comment: PS there is no error in that log, its all okay.

Comment: Do you really want your mysqld to accept connections from all interfaces instead of just 127.1?

Comment: Check the locked query. Tune your my.cnf file. If the locked query for only for any specific database then if possible bring down the website related to that database and check cpu usage. What capacity your vps server have? based on that you may need to tweak the settings.

Comment: @PratapSingh i have checked all the databases and disabled all the databases one by one, and by each one check the server find the same problem

Comment: and what about "show full processlist"?

Comment: i have 3 databases on different ips, each database i had run sql from PhpMyAdmin "show full processlist", and all bring me a successful results

Comment: @Michael roshdy Can you paste your my.cnf file in your question?

Comment: Use something like `innotop` to find out which queries are taking up all the CPU and which user ran the queries.